# Series of books with a flood and a creature masquerading as a woman

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember the author or title, but the story is set down south. One day there was a flood and a new woman showed up. She got involved with the matriarch's son. Turns out she is a creature that came with the flood and her enemies start to disappear. I hope this may sound familiar to someone. I read it in the late 80's, the cover had an eye on it with the town flooded in the background. There were at least 6 books in the series. Thanks

Comment: Does "down south" refer to the southeastern United States?

Comment: Could it be [Blackwater](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/467103.The_Flood) series by Michael McDowell ? Book I is called '_The Flood_' and there appear to be four in the series.

Comment: **Note: as a moderator I can confirm that [the user who confirmed the answer as correct in a comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111166/series-of-books-with-a-flood-and-a-creature-masquerading-as-a-woman#comment299351_111257) is the same person controlling the account that asked the question. Closing as duplicate.**

Answer (score 5):

**[Blackwater series by Michael McDowell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380814897)**

**Stranger shows up**

> McDowell wrote a series called Blackwater that tells the story of a southern family's rise and fall, all due to a stranger who showed up in town one day.

**Flood is in Alabama**

> When a deluge floods a small Alabama town, it leaves something more than river mud behind.....something unexpected.

**Books**

> The Flood is the first in a series of six books in Michael McDowell's BLACKWATER series. This was a fantastic start that had everything you could want to satisfy those that love Southern Gothic books, and leave you wanting to continue the series immediately. A strange woman, stranded by a flood, is rescued in town. What follows in this book is how she takes to life in town and sets about marrying into one of the richest, most influential families there. Elinor is a mysterious character that I can't help but like--both for what I've learned about her, and what I haven't yet.

**Eye on the cover, flooded town**
[image: The Flood]

**Six books in the series**

[image: The Levee]
[image: The House]
[image: The War]
[image: The Fortune]
[image: The Rain]

---

Aside:

Evidently Michael Mcdowell (June 1, 1950 – December 27, 1999) died before he could finish this book.

> His final, unfinished novel "Candles Burning" was completed by novelist Tabitha King and published in 2006.

Comment: So why is "Rain: Blackwater VI" ?

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry that this was a duplicate, but I wasn't a member when I asked it and when I signed up, I asked again. You guys are awesome! thanks again