# Mystery woman appears after flood, marries matriarch's son

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

I have been searching for so long for a certain series of novels.  The only things I remember about the series is that the covers had an eye and a house partly submerged under water. It was a series of 6 books, each with a different colour. The plot concerns a woman who mysteriously appears after a flood in a southern town ruled by the matriarch of a family. The mysterious woman ends up marrying this matriarch's son and then the fun begins: disappearances and good fortune to those who deserve it.

If this sounds at all familiar, please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the series [***Blackwater***](http://www.amazon.ca/Michael-McDowells-Blackwater-The-Flood/dp/0380814897) by Michael McDowell.

[image]

It is indeed a series of 6 books in the Southern Gothic genre.  They concern the mysterious arrival of a woman, Elinor Dammert, to a flooded town ruled by the matriarch of a powerful family — the Caskeys.  Dammert eventually marries the eldest son in the family.  As the story evolves, it turns out that Dammert has a supernatural secret.

The first book was released in **1983**.  The covers are variations of the ones above and below, with each book having a different hue.  The common element is the eye.

[image]

The books in the series were:

- ***The Flood***
- ***The Levee***
- ***The House***
- ***The War***
- ***The Fortune***
- ***Rain***

Comment: I wasn't even aware that there was a Southern Gothic genre.

Comment: @Broklynite : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Gothic  :-)

Comment: Oh I believe you, I just meant I hadn't ever heard of the term as a genre.

Comment: If this is a match (which seems likely, there's a potential duplicate at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111166/23243

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much, my years of searching have ended! I really appreciate the help. I'm glad I found this site.

Comment: @user57615 : Great!  Then please click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct.  :-)

Comment: okay, done. Thank you again :)